# How to allow silverlight to read any file on the file system, not just my documents?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've noticed by default, Silverlight 4 applications only have read access to my documents.

Is there anyway to trust a silverlight application so that it can open a file from any location on the file system.

I can't expect my users to first have to copy files into the my documents folder before upload, is there a way to fully trust a particular silver light app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly no. Silverlight doesn't provide it's own API to access file system outside My Documents. But you can always use COM in elevated trust applications to access any file in the system.

```
    dynamic Fso = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    fso.CreateFolder("D:\\SilverFolder");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.automation.automationfactory(VS.95).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(VS.96).aspx

Comment: Sounds good in theory BUT - Lets say the user needs to select a file first, user does this using  OpenFileDialog, but now, when you call - FileInfo fs = flDialog.File; fs.FullName to get the path, you get a nice access denied error message.

Comment: Are you running SL app in elevated trust mode?
Right click on SL project -> Check Enable running application out of browser. Click Out-of-Browser Settings. Check "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser".

Comment: Sure I am. Have a test, and you'll see the problem. Just browse for any file, then try get the path. I can post some source code if you like.

Comment: Another thing thats bothering me is - I know you set up the elevated trust inside the silverlight application properties, but how would this work in a real world scenario, does the developer just say - this is a trusted application, and the client has no control over it?

Comment: Yep, you are right. Looks like it's not possible to access FullName property of file info outside private doc folders (for security reasons). Sorry I can't help here. And about elevated trust, you should sign you xap file with a certificate. You can generate your cert but it won't be trusted, you need to purchase the certificate from a trusted cert authorities. Of course you can run your xap as full trust with your cert but during installation process, you will get a scary confirmation.

Comment: BTW, you can always create your own OpenFileDialog and SaveDialog. Of course it would be an extra work, but I see this as the only way to accomplish what you want. You can search, read, write, delete etc.  files using FileSystemObject

Comment: I was wondering seeing the mono project implementation if they have one yet, but writing a custom OpenFileDialog might be the solution. I should research more into this.

Comment: I don't think they will have a ready solution to your problem because Moonlight is just an open source, ported implementation of silverlight. anyway good luck with and thanks for accepting the answer.